# Start a new column when MySQL result row count is >= 10

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot figure out how to get my code to create a new HTML column for results, in my table, in a `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {` - when the results returned reach 10, I want a new table column to be created in the same HTML table.

How can I do this? The code I'm using is:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array 
($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_color = ($row_count % 2) ? $color1 : $color2;
    echo '<tr><td align="left" bgcolor=' . $row_color . '> <b>' . $row['manufacturer'] . '</b>: <a href=view_inventory.php?mdl_key=' . $row['mdl_key'] . '&man_key=' . $row['man_key'] . '&cls_key=' . $row['cls_key'] . '&sub_cls_key=' . $row['sub_cls_key'] . '> ' . $row['model'] . '</a></b></td></tr>';
    $row_count++;
}
```

Comment: Please do not use the deprecated `mysql_query` interface in new applications. You should be using [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) or `mysqli`. If you're a novice, you're doing yourself an enormous disservice to be learning an obsolete method of using MySQL.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: You can't just flat out have other people do the work for you. Its programming and you learn by doing. Show us what you tried and we'll help. Or else you'll just kicked out

Comment: I have an example online here: http://hakre.wordpress.com/2012/02/28/some-php-iterator-fun/

Comment: Just set a variable with value 0 initially, like `$i=0;`, then increment it in your while loop, and check its value inside the same loop to create a new html element (whatever you like).

Comment: Updated, I'm kind of experienced - I made a big database, 8 Years ago. I need to read another MySQL book (a new one). - I UPDATED MAIN POST TO SHOW THE WHILE CONDITION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really use the new PDO interface as the mysql extension is deprecated long ago, read [this documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) if you have a choice.

Still, with the old extension, simply do this:

```
$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($rowCount >= 10) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // Do your extra column stuff here.
    }
}
else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // Do your normal stuff here.
    }
}

// It is a good practise to remove variables after 
// loops, this helps releasing memory in large scripts.
unset($rowCount, $row, $result);
```

Comment: I cannot get this method to produce the results I need

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Please provide more specifics.